# Porque me queda la lista en NULL?

Tags: c

Porque me queda la lista en NULL?

---

```
typedef struct Node
{
    int elem;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

typedef struct Node* List;

List empty()
{
    List l = NULL;
    return l;
}

void addl(List l, int e)
{
    Node *n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    n->elem = e;
    n->next = l;
    l = n;
}

int main()
{
    List l = empty();

    addl(l, 1);
    addl(l, 2);

    if (l == NULL)
    {
        printf("IS NULL");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Me devuelve

```
IS NULL
```

¿Por qué? ¿Por qué `addl` no afecta a la lista?

¿No debería apuntar a un nodo? ¿Por qué pasa esto?

Comment: Nótese que `addl` toma el `List` por copia, así que al hacer `l = n` no estas afectando el `l` que tienes en el `main`. Si `l` te queda como `NULL` es porque `empty` te esta retornando `NULL`, que sucede si el `malloc` te falla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrario a lo que piensas, al asignar `l` en la función `addl`, no estás modificando la variable que se encuentra en `main`. Puesto que c pasa una copia de las variables a la función.

Puedes optar por devolver un puntero. Por ejemplo:

```
List* addl(List l, int e);
```

Entonces cuando llames la función deberás guardar el puntero:

```
List l = empty();
l = addl(l, e);
```

O que el primer parámetro sea un puntero a una variable del tipo List.

```
void addl(List* l, int e);
```

En este último caso deberías llamar la función así:

```
List l = empty();
adll(&l, 1);
```